# How do I stop my constant teleporting?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing Minecraft and I decided to make a train so that when it hits the detector rail I teleport using a command block. I connected the command block to the detector rail and on the command block I typed in a random x y z and when I tried it I spawn in the clouds up high in the sky. When I fall back down to earth the train hits the detector rail again and I teleport back up again. How can I get out of this cycle?

Answer (score 9):

If your playing on a server, you can simply disable command blocks with the following configuration line in the server.properties file:

> enable-command-block = false

Then destroy or modify the offending command block.

Comment: I thought there might also be a game rule that you could trigger, but this doesn't appear to be the case, so server properties seem like the only viable option.

Comment: You have to use an External Editor in single player.

Answer (score 3):

Quit and log back in. If you can unload the chunk that the train is in it will stop activating the command block. If it is in a block that remains loaded, such as spawn on a server, I'm not sure there's much you can do without someone else's help or using an external editor.

Answer (score 3):

Wow this is an old thread -

Well, I was having the same issue - here's the vanilla fix - no plugins:

**This is assuming you have daily backups and access to Minecraft 'world' directory via FTP on the hosted site.**

Logout of Minecraft and stop the server.

Login to the FTP and backup the current 'broken world' to your local drive.

Make sure you have a backup of your world, if so, delete the one on the FTP and copy a day old backup of your world from your local drive or the server side to the FTP.

Start the server, login to Minecraft and go to the location of where the offending looping command block **would** be on the 'broken world', and write down the x y z, x y z location *(Press F3 for info)*.

Stop the server, login to the FTP and delete the day old backup 'world' file.

Copy the 'broken world' file from your local drive to the FTP.

Start the server, login to Minecraft.

Type this op command:

/fill *location of command block* minecraft:air

**example:**

*/fill 19 53 351 26 54 350 minecraft:air*

If that works, save it.

/save-all

Hope that helps,
SP

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is going to be using [MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/). Load up the world in MCEdit and remove the command block in question, or the minecart that's triggering it. That way, you can safely and reliably remove only what you want to get rid of.

Comment: ok  i might use that

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you... and i honestly don't want to use external tool. So what i would have to do is create a server with that world and then turn it off with the enabling of commands? Also if this happens to any of you remember the coordinate of the command block... then you can just do /setblock (command block coordiante) air so it gets removed.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally did this on a server I was not owner, and spent a good 20mins trying to fix it. What you do you have to have world edit. You have to be within sight of the command block, and do //sphere water (number of blocks away). The water will destroy the redstone clock, giving you a chance to destroy the commandblock.

Answer (score -1):

If ur in reach of the command block or redstone contraption and ur in creative, u should quickly get water and pour it on top if not go to ur lan world set on to cheats then load it then change ur gamemode to creative and get the bucket of water

Comment: -1 for fill clocks don't work and poorly written // +1 Redstone will pop (break) when water touches it.

Answer (score -3):

you can do /kill to die and escape it

Comment: It will just teleport you again.

Comment: no if you die you go to spawn so you'll be out of the minecart. you could just destroy the minecart now because if it teleports you you won't be in the minecart and you could just destroy the command block.

Comment: No that's not true at all.

Comment: nevermind then pretend i didn't comment